# Old Version of SuperWaba

Tags: java, download, archive

I was searching for the old versions of [SuperWaba](http://www.superwaba.com.br/), but i can't found anyone on internet, because the newer versions of SuperWaba are commercial, but the old versions are free, then if someone have the SuperWaba SDK free version on archive, please post it here. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One more thing: the SuperWaba project with all sources is available at superwaba.sourceforge.net.

But are you sure you can't afford 14.95usd to get a vm and a database? And, honestly, TotalCross is a great piece of software. There are many big companies around the world that adopted it. The next Brazilian Census will be made with it (200 thousands device running on field).

If you're a student, you can just use the demo vm (which expires after 80 hours of continuous use). Then you are allowed to hard reset the device, install it again and use more 80 hours.

regards

Answer (score 2):

Great answer, thanks. I'll like to explain why we do not use GPL. Rick Wild sent us an agreement, when we developed SuperWaba, to allow us to change the license to LGPL. Without this change, no one would be able to produce commercial applications.

In TotalCross, the Java classes are still LGPL.

Regarding why the VM is not GPL/LGPL. The vm was written from SCRATCH, so we are able to put any license we want. We made this specially to not have to be tied to old licenses.

Best regards

```
guich (TotalCross Lead Developer)
```

Answer (score 1):

It does indeed look like the bods at SuperWaba have decided to monetize their investment and you now have to buy TotalCross. Even SuperWaba commercial support is gone as of the end of 2009.

If you're not up to shelling out your hard-earned cash for their product, my suggestion would be to look into the Waba SourceForge project [here](http://waba.sourceforge.net/). It's been a while since it changed, but may be the only way to get something for free.

Alternatively, you could actually buy TotalCross. It seems to me that either it's valuable to you (in which case you wouldn't mind paying for it) or not valuable (in which case, why bother with it). There's a TotalCross demo freely downloadable from that site you linked to, so there's no need to shell out cash until you're happy with it.

I'm sorry if that doesn't fully answer your question (I'm not trying to cause offence) but, if you're a professional developer, I'm sure you don't want to deprive other professional developers of their income.

If you think that the TotalCross bods have somehow broken the GPL (I'm presuming here that SuperWaba was based on Waba and may be subject to GPL licencing itself - that may or may not be the case), another avenue may be to contact them and just ask them what they think about that. It may be that they're still bound by the "make source code available" GPL provision and they may give it to you just to avoid any potential problems.